# Laravel nested eager load specific columns

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I am working with nested eager loading is there a way you can pick out certain columns from the middle relation in `account.user.location` ?

**User Model**

```
 public function account(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Account::class);
    }

 public function location(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }
```

**Account model**

```
 public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Location model**

```
 public function user(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

**Controller method that works**

This method returns the nested relation but i want certain columns from the user relation instead of listing them all.

```
    public function show(string $id)
{
    $film = Film::with([
        'account.user.location'
    ])->findOrFail($id);
}
```

**Controller method that doesn't work**

This is my sample code i've tried to pick out the `name` column from users then display the location relation.

```
    public function show(string $id)
{
    $film = Film::with([
        'account.user:id,name',
        'account.user.location:id',city
    ])->findOrFail($id);
}
```

**Response**

This is the response which is returned its returning the location as null from the not working method

```
 +"account": {#2061
  +"id": "191067a6-4c38-423d-a972-bb3a842ca89e"
  +"user": {#2064
    +"id": "d9f381c1-3899-367c-8d60-6d2bc3db6d23"
    +"name": "Domenick"
    +"location": null
```

Im unsure on how i pick out specific columns from the middle relation and then joining the location. Can i get some assistance on where i am going wrong?

Comment: You need to also select foreign keys used for other eager loaded relations.

Comment: Do you mind adding an example? @Namoshek

Comment: I'm not sure how your relations look like. But whatever object references the other needs to have the foreign key column loaded. For example `locations.user_id` or `users.location_id`. Your code itself is fine, just missing these selects.

Comment: @Namoshek i have just added my models

Comment: In this case use the following eager loading string: `'account.user:id,account_id,location_id,name'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel is loading each level of relationships after another. In other words, if you use `A::with('b.c')->get()`, then Eloquent will first load all `A`s, then all of their referenced `B`s and finally all of the `C`s referenced by the loaded `B`s. The ORM uses navigation properties, i.e. foreign keys, to do so. If you omit these foreign keys on intermediate models, the framework is not able to load the referenced models anymore.

If you'd do it manually, you would use the following queries (used IDs and foreign keys are examples):

```
SELECT * FROM a;                         // returns As with ids 1, 2, 3
SELECT * FROM b WHERE a_id IN (1, 2, 3); // returns Bs with ids 4, 5, 6
SELECT * FROM c WHERE b_id IN (4, 5, 6);
```

---

In your case, it should be sufficient to use the following code:

```
public function show(string $id)
{
    $film = Film::with([
        'account.user:id,account_id,location_id,name',
        'account.user.location:id,city'
    ])->findOrFail($id);
}
```

Comment: i am loading  nested eager load same like here but it returns all fields not specified fields why does it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Update your User Model

```
public function account()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Account::class, 'user_id');
    }

 public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }
```

Update you Account class to

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

In your controller method try this

```
public function show($id)
{
    $film = Film::where('id', $id)
    ->with([
        'account.user:id,name',
        'account.user.location:id',city
    ])->get();
}
```

Comment: It doens'nt help im afraid, i have these relationships already defined apart from user being 'hasMany' because i've different types of accounts. I seem to get this issue when im specificly picking out certain columns from the 2nd relation.

Comment: I have the same thing working here on the current project I'm working on. Please update your questions with your Models and relationships

Comment: i have just added my models

Comment: OK... Let me check them out

Comment: What's your version of Laravel?

Comment: you need to specify `foreign keys` check what I've updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202939/discussion-between-codervine-and-bwinnyz).